# Different x background-positions for rows in a tiled background

Tags: css, background, background-image

I want to create a tiled background in which each row of the background has a random x-offset.  That would be ideal, but if that's not possible with CSS (I think not), at least what's the best way to use a single image to create a body background in which this several (let's say 4) rows of this image have different x positions?

Something like:

```
IMAGEIMAGEIMAGEIMAGE
MAGEIMAGEIMAGEIMAGEI
AGEIMAGEIMAGEIMAGEIM
GEIMAGEIMAGEIMAGEIMA
IMAGEIMAGEIMAGEIMAGE
MAGEIMAGEIMAGEIMAGEI
AGEIMAGEIMAGEIMAGEIM
GEIMAGEIMAGEIMAGEIMA
```

Comment: make a fiddle to help you what u need exactly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If CSS3 is appropriate for your project, you can use multiple backgrounds to do this.

Make an image that is twice the height of your pattern, with the top half filled with your pattern, and the bottom half transparent.

Then use multiple backgrounds to position them accordingly like so:

```
.div {
    background: url(path/to/image.png) 0 0 repeat,
                url(path/to/image.png) 0 {height of image in pixel} repeat
}
```

Its not a random offset, but with enough variations to this, it would be hard to tell the difference.

If you want to add to the perceived randomness, have a look at [this post](http://designfestival.com/the-cicada-principle-and-why-it-matters-to-web-designers/).

Comment: very interesting approach for up-to-date browsers !! and thank you for the link: amazing stuff \o/ beyond that, people should just never forget that a) png files _are_ larger than jpg files and b) transparency _has_ a non-negligting cost.

Comment: I find that for repeat color patterns, you can get very good compression ratios using pngs. I recommend [this tool](http://imageoptim.com/) for getting the most out of the compression (Mac only)

Comment: You're absolutely right! thanks for the link (mac -> good guess !). And I'm far from saying that it's bad to use png, it's just that people (i'm not saying you) easily forget that kind of details. And if I put my remark here, its because some users might want to have more than 2 different lines, say 6. In that case, your png image will be 6* taller than the original one, with ~83% of transparency.

Comment: By "enough variations" you mean that if I wanted 4 differnt rows, I would have a png that is bottom 3/4 transparent, right? The cicada link is awesome, thank you, Clark!

Comment: Btw, for my image (around 240x120), the png with image and 3 transparent rows weighed as much as a jpg with 3 image rows at 9 quality. So weight-wise the empty-row png doesn't seem to win that much  (at least for a small number of rows), and the jpgs additionally work on non-CSS3 browsers.

Comment: Yes, this is what we discussed upper. png can be magic, but the main drawback (in some cases at least) is that it has a lossless compression, thus it _will_ always be larger than an equivalent jpg picture (which has a lossy compression). I would recommend Clark's approach for small size pictures (like the example in the cicada link), and rather go for the js solution for large picture like yours. Use the jpg one, and generate around 5 divs -> no real overhead.

Answer (score 1):

what would be the size of your image? If is is very small, an *easy* solution would be to do that in photoshop/paint. The resulting image would be 4x larger, but for small images (read less than 25ko), I think it is by far the easiest way. At least I don't see any *easy* CSS solution to your problem.

If your picture is quite big and you know its height, you could eventually have the following approach: http://jsfiddle.net/7GPTy/

The idea is to create several divs at `z-index:-1` of `height == image_height` and absolute position with different left values... i'd see that as a coarse but working solution

```
var mybody = document.getElementById('body');
var bodyHeight = mybody.offsetHeight;
var imgHeight = 49; // you could get the size by opening the file
var offsetLines = 4; // this is the number of offset you asked, but you can change that!
var nbOfLines = Math.ceil(bodyHeight/imgHeight);
for(var i=0; i<nbOfLines; i++){
    var newBgDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newBgDiv.className = 'backgroundImg imgOffset_'+(i%offsetLines);
    newBgDiv.style.top = (i*imgHeight) + 'px';
    newBgDiv.style.height = imgHeight + 'px';
    newBgDiv.style.width = '100%';
    mybody.appendChild(newBgDiv);
}
```

to go through the js code quickly, I basically get the height of the page and divide it by the height of the picture to know how many divs i have to create to generate the entire background. Once done, you simply define the number of different row offset you want (`offsetLines`) and you generate your divs.

In my example, the offset depends on the size of the window (try to resize horizontally your window, you'll see that the offset changes). You can of course fix it to a defined number of pixels !

Comment: Nice, this could indeed be made to work to generate truly random x-offsets for the bg. Probably some rendering overhead for the browser for the extra divs, but probably not that bad...

Comment: Well it really depends on the size of your picture. If you have a >100px high picture, the overhead is ridiculous (it adds around 10divs to your website). And if your picture is smaller than 100px, you should rather go for photoshop/paint and simply print it :)